# Regex: How to match for exact length of multiple values?

Tags: java, regex

How can I use this pattern: `[A-Za-z0-9]{10}` to also match to other text sizes like: 12 and 25?

I tried to make it like:

1. `[A-Za-z0-9]{10|12|25}`
2. `([A-Za-z0-9]){10}|{12}|{25}`

But it didn't succeed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use alternations if you need to match specific sized only:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{10}|[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|[A-Za-z0-9]{25})$
```

If you want to match symbols within a range, say, from 10 to 25, you can use

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{10,25}$
```

Also, `[A-Za-z0-9]` can be replaced with `\p{Alnum}` (see [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

> **`\p{Alnum}`**   An alphanumeric character:`[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`

Java [code demo](http://ideone.com/oAO1AT) with `String#matches` (that does not require anchors):

```
System.out.println("1234567890".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]{10}|[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|[A-Za-z0-9]{25}")); 
// => true, 10  Alnum characters
System.out.println("12345678901".matches("\\p{Alnum}{10}|\\p{Alnum}{12}|\\p{Alnum}{25}"));
// => false, 11 Alnum characters
System.out.println("123456789012".matches("\\p{Alnum}{10}|\\p{Alnum}{12}|\\p{Alnum}{25}"));
// => true, 12  Alnum characters
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have

```
([A-Za-z0-9]){10}|([A-Za-z0-9]){12}|([A-Za-z0-9]){25}
```

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9]` can be expressed more simply with `\p{Alnum}`, making the regex:

```
(\\p{Alnum}){10}|(\\p{Alnum}){12}|(\\p{Alnum}){25}
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid useless work for the regex engine, you can write:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{10}(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{13})?)?
```

in this way the first characters are parsed only once.