# How to apply size annotation for a field which can be either of two sizes

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, size

In my spring boot application I have a size validation on one of field in my dto. Now as per new requirement field size can be either 18 or 36. Earlier it was 36 so I had done like this:

```
@Size(min=36,max = 36,message = "id length should be 36")
```

Now as I have to validate against two sizes, Is there any way to do it with the annotation itself ?

Thanks,

Comment: An annotation is only metadata an annotation does nothing but provide information. WIth the `@Size` annotation that isn't possible so you will have to write your own validator for this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom validator Annotation.

In **CustomSize.java**

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomSizeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CustomSize{

  String message() default "{CustomSize.invalid}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default { };

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

In **CustomSizeValidator.java**

```
class CustomSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomSize, String> {

   @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      try { 
        
          if(value.length()==18 || value.length()==36){
              return true;
             }else{
               return false;
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Use this in your POJO code.

```
@CustomSize
private String xyz;
```

OR
use `@Pattern`

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|[A-Za-z0-9]{36})$")
```

For Pattern see more here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311990/1459174